# Although mine is not an atomic vector I'm still getting the error: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, text-mining

I'm trying to perform Text mining on a csv datafile.

The source I'm referring to has this performed on the Twitter data. But I want to do a similar thing on text data stored in a csv.

I'm trying out the following code:

```
data <- read.csv("Joined_Tab.csv")
dtweets <- data[1:30,]

for(i in 1:20)
{
  cat(paste("[ [", i, "] ]", sep=""))
  writeLines(strwrap(dtweets[[i]]$getText(), width=25))
}
```

Here both `data` and `dtweets` are dataframes. But when I'm trying to use the `getText()` I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in dtweets[[i]]$getText : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

But a dataframe is not an atomic vector. (I also tried converting the dataframe to a list, still the same error, although a list is also not an atomic vector)

Here is the `str()`

```
'data.frame': 30 obs. of 2 variables: 
  $ S.No : int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 
  $ Tweet: chr "Good cooperation" "engaged team u always get valuable support" "Still klm with domain specific dcm helps to attract clients" "Support with gdp also on short note works nice"
```

Where am I going wrong??

And are there better ways to perform Text mining in a csv file?

I'm a beginner in R so please suggest me accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the output of `str(dtweets)`.

Comment: Maybe want `dtweets[[i]][[ getText() ]]`. Whatever follows `$` is not evaluated.

Comment: output of `str(dtweets)` is: 
'data.frame': 30 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ S.No : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Tweet: chr  "Good cooperation" "engaged team u always get valuable support" "Still klm with domain specific dcm helps to attract clients" "Support with gdp also on short note works nice" ...

Comment: `dtweets[[i]][[ getText() ]]` didn't work either:
 `for(i in 1:20)
  cat(paste("[ [", i, "] ]", sep=""))
  writeLines(strwrap( dtweets[[i]][[ getText() ]], width=25))
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `[[` operator on a data.frame (which is a list too) you get the corresponding variable, so `dtweets[[1]]` gives the number (1 2 3...) and `dtweets[[2]]` gives you the tweets ("Good cooperation", ...). For `i` greater than 2, you should get an error (`Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds`) cause there are no more variables.
Also, after you use `tweets[[2]]` the result is a vector! Not a data.frame anymore! Additionally, what you put after the `$` should be a function. In R, functions need the parenthesis to be evaluated, even without arguments. 
So, even if `dtweets[[i]]` will give you something that can be indexed with the `$`, and that sub-thing is named `getText()`, you need the quotes: `dtweets[[i]]$'getText()'` in order to index over special characters. My guess it getText is actually a function, so you need something like `getText(dtweets[i,2])`. That's a guess unless you show the code of the `getText` function.